# monitoring server and website - design issue

Tags: asp.net, database, indexing, monitoring

I have an ASP.NET Web Application that constantly monitors for new RSS Feed from Delicious and stores results in a database. Apart from this, I will need to query the database in order to show results where needed. I am using a Timer Event, so that the indexing of new feed from delicious is done every 15 minutes and this is an ongoing process.

Just to be clear I have a web application that contains 2 pages:
 1. default,aspx : indexes
 2. recommendations.aspx : queries the database for recommendations

Now I have some problems:

I placed the timer event in the default.aspx page so that every 15 minutes, it initiates the event and starts indexing. However, problem with this is that I have to be on that page for it to index. Ideally I want that this process to work in the background without disturbing the user.

secondly, If the user had to click on recommendations.aspx page, and queries the database, it will keep waiting for localhost.., since it will be busy indexing.

I need suggestions for a proper way to design this system and if it is possible, please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say, "the indexing of new feed from delicious is done every 15 minutes", does that just mean you store the results of the RSS feed every 15 minutes?

Comment: I do some work, and then store it, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly say, the code behind `index.aspx` will only run when the page is loaded.

What you really want to use is some kind of background process -- a Windows service, in other words. The process for a Windows service is always kept running, so you can have long-running timers that can do polling and suchlike.

A walkthrough for this is on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> I placed the timer event in the
>   default.aspx page so that every 15
>   minutes, it initiates the event and
>   starts indexing. However, problem with
>   this is that I have to be on that page
>   for it to index. Ideally I want that
>   this process to work in the background
>   without disturbing the user.

You probably just need a script whose execution is controlled through Windows "Scheduled Tasks". The timing is controlled by "Scheduled Tasks"; the downloading and database updating are controlled by the script. No real need for a web page at all.

Comment: OK, Thanks! do you have any links that can help me do what you said?

Comment: No, I was thinking of something along the lines of the old VB scripts. Some old servers that I've worked on had VB scripts that read a database to see whether someone needed to be notified of something (that's one script), and then sent them an email (that's another script). In your case I'd be looking for something that would consume an RSS feed (one script), parse it (maybe the same script), and insert the contents into a database (another script). My intuition tells me that would be simpler--maybe a lot simpler--than programming a Windows service, but I could be wrong.